# JPA: Map a Map<Enum, Entity>

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

i want to Map a map in JPA, but I get a Exception:
My java-code looks like that:

Issue.java:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
    name="ISSUE_EMPLOYEE",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ISSUE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
)
@MapKeyColumn(name="EMPLOYEEPOSITION_ID")
@MapKeyConvert("myEnumConverter")
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Map<EmployeePosition, Employee> namedEmployees = new Hashtable<EmployeePosition, Employee>();
```

`EmployeePosition` is a `Enum` and`Employee` is a `Entity`.

I get this Exception :

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEES": invalid identifier
>
> Error Code: 904
>   Call: INSERT INTO ISSUE_EMPLOYEE (ISSUE_ID, EMPLOYEES, EMPLOYEEPOSITION_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>       bind => [27, [B@18b85d, SERVICE]

It seems to ignore the `@JoinColumn` annotation and tries to insert the object in the DB.
What´s wrong with my mapping/Is it possible to match Entities like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need `@OneToMany` instead of `@ElementCollection` when value of a `Map` is an entity. Something like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "ISSUE_EMPLOYEE",
    joinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "ISSUE_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumn = @JoinColumn("EMPLOYEE_ID"))
@MapKeyColumn(name="EMPLOYEEPOSITION_ID") 
private Map<EmployeePosition, Employee> namedEmployees = new Hashtable<EmployeePosition, Employee>();
```

**EDIT:** The mapping above works fine in Hibernate, but doesn't work in EclipseLink. `EMPLOYEEPOSITION_ID` column in `ISSUE_EMPLOYEE` is created, but not used in queries. It happens not only with enum keys, but also with other primitive types.

It looks like a bug in EclipseLink. I can't find in in [their Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/), so perhaps it would be better to report it.

Comment: I tried your annotations. I did the joinTable-Annotation like this '@JoinTable(name="ISSUE_EMPLOYEE",      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ISSUE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    )' 
It now does this insert-statement: 
"Call: INSERT INTO ISSUE_EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_ID, ISSUE_ID) VALUES (?, ?)" 
So it doesn´t insert the EmployeePosition...Any ideas?

Comment: @Lodger: Im'm not sure about your `@MapKeyConvert` annotation. Have you tried to replace it with `@MapKeyEnumerated`?

Comment: Yes, i tried the @MapKeyEnumerated instead of @MapKeyConvert, but it throws the same Exception.

Comment: finally reported it in their [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355697)

Comment: thanks this helped me a lot. For those using an Enum as key, they can even use: @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)